# Limiting grep search

Tags: shell, grep

Please help! Must use grep for this assignment. Must control grep function to search for a string strictly in a given field (Sadly no delimiters)
Search field is characters 12-26. Must check if user input name of choice exists or not (variable "$name"). if so, then must cut out specific fields (No problem with that)
My code for this point:

```
...(previous lines of code & conditions..)
while read line
do
  grep -E "^.{11}[ :alpha: ]{1,15}$name" | cut -c31-43 #(eg. opponent)# 
done
...
#grep start point and end point.
```

How can I add the option for the user input variable `$name` into the regexp??

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is fixed-length fields, you can just pad the name to the appropriate length:

```
SCAN=$( echo "$name                       " | cut -b1-15 )

...(previous line of code & conditions)

# We do not need a loop; grep will read all lines as "while read" would
grep -E "^.{11}${SCAN}" | cut -c31-43

# (unless we must do something more inside the while/done, of course)
```